# Duplicate MySQL db as slave, ignoring one row

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am setting up a "slave" instance of Wordpress (2nd database, 2nd install of Wordpress), and want the 2nd database to be a slave of the primary db, with the exception of which plugins are active.

I would use something like `replicate_wild_ignore_table`, but unfortunately the record for which plugins are active in Wordpress is a row in a table, vs an entire table.

We need the 2nd instance of Wordpress because we need it to do some different things than the primary instance does, and it needs to have difference plugins active than the primary one does. But, the slave database needs to have the exact same data for most other tables in the db. So my thinking is that the 2nd db is a slave of the primary, with the exception of the plugins row in the `wp_options` table.

Is this the best way to go about this? If so, some guidance would be much appreciated.

My plan thus far is to sync the two dbs by using this guide: https://torbjornzetterlund.com/how-to-setup-a-mysql-replication-database-for-wordpress/

In essence this method boils down to the master writing its transactions to this log:

```
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db = wordpressdb
```

Then the slave reads this log and updates itself:

```
relay-log               = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db            = wordpressdb
```

There's more of course, but that's essentially where the magic happens.

Comment: How do you sync the db?

Comment: Updated the question with this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set up the replica as identical to its master.

Connect to the replica database and disable certain plugins by changing the data. See https://perishablepress.com/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/

But someone could re-enable the plugin on the master, and that change would flow through to the replica and re-enable it there. You can create a trigger on the `wp_options` table on the replica, to ensure the plugins you don't want stay inactive.

```
CREATE TRIGGER disable_all_plugins BEFORE UPDATE ON wp_options
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.option_value = IF(NEW.option_name='active_plugins', 'a:0:{}', NEW.option_value);
```

*(That trigger is not tested, I provide it only as a starting point. You are responsible for understanding what it does and changing it to suit your needs.)*

Make sure the master uses statement-based binary logs, because [row-based binary logs don't execute triggers on the replica](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-triggers.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info @Bill Karwin, this looks like it. Will be giving this a go tomorrow. If it works for me, I'll tick this as the answer.

Comment: this did the trick and I was able to extend this to accomplish a few other trigger updates needed to make it roll smoothly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could give *[WP Migrate DB Pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/)* a try. This is the plugin I have used to migrate a dev site to a live site.

The plugin can pull or push data between sites, including media files. It allows you not to migrate the ***active_plugins*** setting, so you could keep the other site using their own plugins.

Please check the video for more details. https://youtu.be/fHFcH4bCzmU?t=3m37s

It supports [WP-CLI](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/doc/cli-push-pull-subcommand/), so you can write some code to automate this process.

Comment: Another interesting way to go about it. Will take a look at this. Thanks @ucheng.

Comment: this plugin is super interesting! going to give this method a test as well, though what Bill Karwin answered was a more direct answer to the original question. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: No worries! @PaulIsLoud